# In Objective-c is performSelector executed inline or is it posted for execution as a different event?

Tags: objective-c, selector

There are plenty of reasons why this matters.  Here's a simple example if you weren't using ARC.

```
[instance performSelector:selector withObject:objectA];
[objectA release];    // Did the selector actually finish executing
                      // in the line above so everyone's done with objectA
                      // or did the selector merely get scheduled in the line
                      // above, and is yet to execute, so objectA had better
                      // not be released yet?
```

I've done some research and context clues seem to point to selector getting done inline.  But I haven't seen any definitive statement anywhere I've looked, that states it gets executed inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`performSelector:withObject:` is executed synchronously (block until the method finished).

Use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to execute method asynchronously on main thread (return immediately and execute later).

Use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` to execute method asynchronously on background thread (return immediately and execute on different thread).

Note:
`performSelector` and its friends should be avoid because it is undefined behaviour if you use them on method with incompatible method signature.

> The aSelector argument should identify a method that takes no arguments. For methods that return anything other than an object, use NSInvocation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:

Comment: @JoshCaswell It is not really deprecated (I've updated wording) but as the document said, `NSInvocation` should be used most of the time. use `performSelector` can easily add bugs that hard to catch. (e.g. change method signature from return `NSNumber` to `double`)

Comment: I didn't want to ask 2 questions in 1, but I also see a lot of chatter about selectors can't return a primitive etc.  But I can't find any definitive statement saying "all selectors must return an NSObject*"  In fact all my selectors are are -(void)myFunction.  They work, but nonetheless is what I'm doing technically illegal?

Comment: @JoeC Yes it is undefined behaviour. If you takes the return argument and do something with it, you app will likely to crash. (it may depends on arch/platform/version)

Answer (score 0):

> Did the selector actually finish executing in the line above so
>   everyone's done with objectA or did the selector merely get scheduled
>   in the line above, and is yet to execute, so objectA had better not be
>   released yet?

It doesn't matter, for memory management purposes. Memory management in Cocoa is *local* -- you only need to care what your function does; you don't need to know, and shouldn't care, what other functions do internally, to manage memory correctly (ignoring retain cycles). As long as you're done with your owning reference, you should release it. It doesn't matter to you if other people are done with it.

This is because, according to Cocoa memory management rules, any function which needs to store it for use beyond the function call is required to retain it and release it when it's done (because the function cannot assume that the object lives beyond the calling scope otherwise). Any function which uses an argument asynchronously (e.g. `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` etc.) does indeed retain the object and release it when it's done.

Alternately, think about it this way: How does ARC work? How does ARC know whether a function uses its argument synchronously or asynchronously? It doesn't. There is no annotation that tells the compiler whether a function uses something synchronously or asynchronously. Yet ARC does it correctly. That means you can too, without knowing whether the function uses its argument synchronously or asynchronously.